# NOIP2 won't run

Tags: raspbian

I am trying to configure noip2 client on my Rasp. Building produced some warnings like:

```
#:/home/admin/builds/noip2/noip-2.1.9-1# make
gcc -Wall -g -Dlinux -DPREFIX=\"/usr/local\" noip2.c -o noip2 
noip2.c: In function ‘dynamic_update’:
noip2.c:1595:6: warning: variable ‘i’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
  int i, x, is_group, retval, response;
      ^
noip2.c: In function ‘domains’:
noip2.c:1826:13: warning: variable ‘x’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
         int x;
             ^
noip2.c: In function ‘hosts’:
noip2.c:1838:20: warning: variable ‘y’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
         int     x, y, z;
                    ^
```

After `make install` finishes, conf files are created etc I get  the following when I try to ran it:

```
:/home/admin/builds/noip2/noip-2.1.9-1# noip2 -c /path/to/conf/file
Can't get shared memory. (Invalid argument) Ending!
```

My version:

```
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 8.0 (jessie)
Release:    8.0
Codename:   jessie
```

Any solutions? 
Thanks!

Comment: Yeah... same problem here. Seems to be something with the new kernel

Comment: @kadavar Use `ddclient` as alternative.